# Function argument in python : not raising NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-3.4

The way I learn in python argument to use a function with an argument is as follow:

```
def res(arg1, arg2):
    try:
        print(a+b)  # it prints result.. shouldn't code be break here?
        return a + b  # this also returns a result.
    except NameError:
        return "failed."
a = 2
b = 3
print(res(a, b))
```

I am expecting that in such case function should raise `NameError` and it should be handled in except block but it is not raising any kind of error instead it works with both `arg1+arg2` and `a +b` am I missing something here? need any kind of help to understand and overcome this.

Comment: `a` and `b` are globals in your module, and all globals are available to your function.

Comment: as this is interpreted language shouldn't be a global variable defined before function definition?

Comment: No, the globals just need to be defined before you _call_ the function. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.